# Uploading file to play controller using jQuery Post

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, playframework-2.0

Can you please provide me a sample for uploading/ posting a file to play controller using `jQuery`

I am using `play 2.0.1` and `jQuery 1.7.2`

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Everything's described:

1. For HTML part: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758614/1066240
2. For controller: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/JavaFileUpload

All you need is just make sure, you are using the same name for field with file (in Ajax sample it's `file` in Play's doc it's `picture`).

BTW: There are also *ready-to-use* solutions for HTML/JS part: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload